# Looping through table rows + grabbing attributes

Tags: jquery, html-table, each, rows

I'm trying to loop through table rows, pass in an object, grab each row's data-filter, and check it against the data I'm passing in (key value pairs). My below code isn't grabbing the data-filter value. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
   <tr data-filter="1">
     <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-filter="2">
     <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-filter="3">
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#table > tr').each(function(data) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var filter = $this.attr(data-filter);
  console.log(filter);
}
```

Comment: Try `$this.data("filter");` instead of `$this.attr(data-filter);`

Comment: Or just put quotes around 'data-filter'.

Comment: `$this.attr('data-filter');`

Answer (score 4):

One thing to consider, when the code is rendering in browser, browser will automatically added `tbody` tag inside your `table`, then this `$('#table > tr')` selector will failed as this will select direct `tr` element but right now in the browser the direct child is a `tbody` though. If you're aware then let continue to the another case is :

```
$('#table > tbody > tr').each(function(data) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var filter = $this.data('filter'); // or var filter = $this.attr('data-filter');
   console.log(filter);
}
```